# ConnectionString wthout username and password bugtracker

Tags: connection-string, bug-tracking, bug-tracker

I am trying to setup BugTracker on my local machine.

My SQL Server used Windows Authentication.

My connection string looks as under

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=MyPCName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

**Error I am getting**

Unable to connect.

Cannot open database "BugTracker" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MyPCName\ASPNET'.

Check Web.config file "ConnectionString" setting.

Any Idea how can i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It's using Windows Authentication. If running under IIS, you need to determine the account that is executing your ASP.Net application. You then add permission for that account to SQL Server.

For example, IIS on Windows 7 runs all App Pools with an account called "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" by default. You can configure your app pool to use a different account, which would be recommended for security reasons.

But that should get you past the security issue.